# Display output of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a javascript function that outputs the date modified of a sharepoint list.

Here is my code:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var list = lists.getByTitle("Tasks");
ctx.load(list, "LastItemModifiedDate");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        var lastmodified = list.get_lastItemModifiedDate();
    },
    function() {}
);
```

Which I got from this [link](http://chuvash.eu/2012/09/24/jsom-last-modified-date-of-a-list/). But I am unsure of how to display the output from the function. I tried to display the output in the html tag but still no luck.

Comment: Can't you add a `console.log` line and past it in your browser's developer tools console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this after you capture the lastmodified date?

```
// Names are generic and can be changed
var displayElement = document.getElementById("lastModifiedDisplay");
displayElement.innerHTML = lastmodified
```

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Comment: still not able to display the date. Is there a way to 'debug' to view the values being passed like we can in visual studio?

Comment: Try using `console.log(lastmodified);`. You can view your JS console with Chrome's dev tools or Firebug. That should show you the value of the variable.